# How to Access text files uploaded to Heroku that is running with Python Script

Tags: python, heroku

apologies upfront. I am an extreme newbie and this is probably a very easy question. After much trial and error, I set up an app on Heroku that runs a python script that scrapes data off of a website and stores it in a text file. (I may switch the output to a .csv file). The script and app are running on a Heroku Scheduler, so the scraping takes place on a schedule and the data automatically gets written to the file that is on the Heroku platform. I simply want to download the particular output file occasionally so that I can look at it. (Part of the data that is scraped is being tweeted on a twitter bot that is part of the script.)

(Not sure that this is relevant but I uploaded everything through Git.)

Many thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command `heroku run cat path/to/file.txt`, but keep in mind that Heroku uses ephemeral storage, so you don't have any guarantee that your file will be there.

For example, Heroku restarts your dynos every 24 hours or so. After that you won't have that file anymore. The general practice is to store files on some external storage provider like Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1):

Not just ephemeral, but *immutable*, which means you can't write to the file system. You'll have to put the file in something like S3, or just put the data into a database like Postgres.

Comment: Thanks. I think that that nails it for me. I learned by trial and error exactly what you posit - that  these are ephemeral and immutable files on Heroku.  ... I am trying another approach which would have the python script write the data to a google sheet via gspread. But I am having trouble having gspread import into the python script and work. I will post separately on this.